# OpenCL and OpenGL interop extension not working (clGetGLContextInfoKHR crash)

Tags: opengl, rust, opencl

I'm struggling with getting GL+CL to work together.

I've been following [this tutorial](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/opencl-and-opengl-interoperability-tutorial.html). In my code I first call `clGetPlatformIDs` and retrieve the first (and only) platform. I also get my `gl_context` from SDL2. Then I want to query the device used by OpenGL with help of `clGetGLContextInfoKHR`. I successfully obtain this function with `clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform(platform_id, "clGetGLContextInfoKHR")` but unfortunately when I call it, I get a segmentation fault. My code is written in Rust but I use [low level OpenCL binding](https://docs.rs/cl-sys/0.4.2/cl_sys/), so it looks almost like its C counterpart.

```
    pub fn new(gl_context: &GLContext) -> Result<Self, ClGlError> {
        println!("Initialising OpenCL context");
        let raw = unsafe { gl_context.raw() };
        println!("Getting default opencl platform");
        let platform_id = Self::default_platform()?; // this is valid and not null
        let mut props:[cl_sys::cl_context_properties;5] = [
            //OpenCL platform
            cl_sys::CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM as cl_sys::cl_context_properties, platform_id as cl_sys::cl_context_properties,
            //OpenGL context
            cl_sys::CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR,   raw as cl_sys::cl_context_properties,
            0
        ];
        let mut device: cl_device_id = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let p: *mut cl_device_id = (&mut device) as *mut cl_device_id;
        let fn_name = b"clGetGLContextInfoKHR\0" as *const u8 as *const i8;
        println!("Getting clGetGLContextInfoKHR");
        let clGetGLContextInfoKHR = unsafe{clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform(platform_id, fn_name ) as cl_sys::clGetGLContextInfoKHR_fn};
        if clGetGLContextInfoKHR.is_null(){
            // error handling here
        }
        println!("Getting device"); // this is the last thing I see before segfault
        unsafe{
            (*clGetGLContextInfoKHR)(props.as_mut_ptr(),cl_sys::CL_CURRENT_DEVICE_FOR_GL_CONTEXT_KHR,std::mem::size_of::<cl_device_id>(),device as *mut c_void,std::ptr::null_mut());
        }

        panic!("All good") // this is never reached
    }
```

I have a fairly new Graphics card which supports `cl_khr_gl_sharing`.
Here is clinfo

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 11.2.162
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_device_uuid
  Platform Extensions function suffix             NV

  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     GeForce GTX 960
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  460.80
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_device_uuid
```

Perhaps the most important clue might be that I tried a bunch of other libraries that build on top of opencl and in all of them, whenever I called `clGetGLContextInfoKHR` (wrapped in safer and higher-level API) it crashed. I think it's very unlikely that all those libraries had bugs in their code, so probably it's some problem in my environment. However, as you can see, my graphics card clearly supports all necessary extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why `clGetGLContextInfoKHR` is failing but I figured out that it's not really necesary to call it.

Instead you may just use this on Linux

```
cl_context_properties properties[] = {
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties) glXGetCurrentContext(),
    CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties) glXGetCurrentDisplay(),
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties) platform,
    0
};
```

this on Windows

```
cl_context_properties properties[] = {
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties) wglGetCurrentContext(),
    CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties) wglGetCurrentDC(),
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties) platform,
    0
};
```

or this on OS X

```
CGLContextObj glContext = CGLGetCurrentContext();
CGLShareGroupObj shareGroup = CGLGetShareGroup(glContext);
cl_context_properties properties[] = {
    CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE,
    (cl_context_properties)shareGroup,
    0
};
```

More info can be found in the book

> OpenCL in Action: How to Accelerate Graphics and Computations